# How to pull data from mySQL based on search in iOS app

Tags: ios, mysql, objective-c, database, mapkit

Hey I am very new to working with databases but I figured I needed one for an app I am working on.  Essentially I have the user search for a location and also have a search radius.  From here I want to be able to filter through the different locations on the database and display the ones that are within the radius of the location searched.  Inside my database the locations have latitudes and longitudes that I figured I could use to determine the distance from the location searched.  Like I said I am very new to databases and just need a point in the right direction.  Currently I have the app to simply load all the locations inside my database on a map with MapKit but have no idea how to use the search to filter through said locations.  Thanks!

Comment: Does the database live on the phone?  If so, are you using Codedata?

Comment: Im not sure exactly what you mean by living on the phone but I use php and json to bring the data from the db to the app.  Is that what you are referring to?